# Where is Anacron mailing job output?

Tags: cron

I have a job that is run by anacron. In the syslog I see messages like:

```
Apr  6 06:11:09 host anacron[1031]: Job `myJob' terminated (mailing output)
```

but I never see that mail. If I run that same job through cron the output is mailed to /var/mail/username. Where is anacron mailing the output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely `anacron` is executing the jobs as root, so the mail isn't being sent to your user. You might what to use `/etc/aliases` to get the mail at your normal address. Like so:

`root:         your@email.com`

Or to use a file:

`root:         /file/name`

See [`man 5 aliases`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man5/aliases.5.html) for more information.

Comment: nice tip on using aliases and also on directing to a file

Comment: Does this file `/etc/aliases` exist on ubuntu xenial?

Answer (score 5):

In case You use `anacron` on a home computer – one **without a mail server** installed –, You might want to see the logs (`stdout`) and errors (`stderr`) of your scheduled tasks in a log file for debugging. To do so, You can add [redirections](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) to your `anacrontab` file like this:

```
# period  delay  job-identifier  command
1         0      backup          /home/me/backup.sh 1>>/home/me/backup.log 2>>/home/me/backup-errors.log
```